# Node numbering problem?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (2) at (1,0);
\coordinate (3) at (0.5,1);
\coordinate (4) at (0,0);
\coordinate (5) at ($(1)!.5!(2)$);
\coordinate (6) at ($(2)!.5!(3)$);
\coordinate (7) at ($(3)!.5!(1)$);
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [below] {\i};

\foreach \i in {5}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [below] {\i};
\foreach \i in {6,7}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [above] {\i};

\draw (1)--(2)--(3)--(4);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: And the question is? Which seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Between line(1)-(2) I want (4)

Comment: Then use `\foreach \i in {5}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [below] {4};` or just 
`\fill (5) circle (1pt) node [below] {4};` since a loop for just one element is redundant.

Comment: Instead of `\coordinate (4) at (0,0);` did you perhaps mean to say `\coordinate (4) at ($(1)!.5!(2)$);` so that the `(4)` is where the current `(5)` is?  In your MWE you have `(4)` at the origin which is where `(1)` is.

Comment: please edit your question to include an actual question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=-2pt]

\coordinate (1) at (1:210);
\coordinate (2) at (1:-30);
\coordinate (3) at (1:90);

\coordinate (4) at ($(1)!.5!(2)$);
\coordinate (5) at ($(2)!.5!(3)$);
\coordinate (6) at ($(3)!.5!(1)$);
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node[label=90+\i*120:\i] {};

%\foreach \i in {5}
%\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [below] {\i};
\foreach \i in {4,...,6}
\fill (\i) circle (1pt) node[label=150+\i*120:\i] {};

\draw (1)--(2)--(3)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Terse question, equally terse answer. +1

Comment: @Jubobs as your terse blue symbol ;-)